# Safari no longer auto-filling forms

Tags: safari

Safari Version 13.1 (15609.1.20.111.8) on macOS 10.15.4 (19E287)

Some time in one of the recent upgrades to Safari, form auto-fill stopped working. When I go to a form there is a widget for auto-fill, but when I click it all I get is a single item, "Customize". Selecting that pops up a dialog-like box with my contact info, and if I click OK on that it puts my name into the field.

That works to a degree, but then fails completely: this enters my name in the first field, but does not enter any additional information in any other fields. So for instance, the address field is not filled out. A widget appears in that box, but clicking it produces nothing at all.

Am I missing a setting or something? It seems to be completely broken.

This is particularly ironic, because the actual form I re-noticed this on is Apple's Safari Bug reporter, where it asks you to fill in your name and email. Neither filled in, and the email auto-fill is dead.